# Reading from a text file into an array

Tags: java, arrays, text, io

Hi im currently trying to do a hackerearth challenge sum of medians and it involves me reading from a text file and storing the values in an array. The first value has to be stored in a variable N which i am able to do but the the remaining values have to be stored in an array. This is where i become stuck. i have to read each value line by line and then store it in the array .
this is my code that i have been trying to get it working on but i just cant see where im going wrong.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 

class TestClass { 
 public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception { 

 // read number of data from system standard input. 
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
 String line = br.readLine(); 
 int N = Integer.parseInt(line); 
 int i = 1;
 int[] myIntArray = new int[N];
  // median sum 
 long SumMedians = 0; 
 int median = 0;


 while (i<N)

     //read one line file and parse as an integer
     //store the value in an array
 { 

     myIntArray [i] = Integer.parseInt(line);

 i = i + 1; // increment i so i is the total numbers read
 }
```

so as i said i must increment through the text file storing each value on the line in an array. Any help would be amazing thanks

The text file will look like this

5

10

5

1

2

15

one string per line, which i have to pass into an integer. 
what i will be doing is after i store the value from the line into the array i will be sorting it and finding its medium and then repeat this process until all the values from the text file have been read.

The problem which i am trying to do is this one

http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/sum-of-medians-1/

Comment: Do you know what format the line will be in? Is there 1 integer per line? multiple integers per line seperated by spaces? Multiple integers per line seperated by colons (:)?

Comment: Edit this post and show us, how your text file looks like.

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading from a text file (and not from standard input which is what you're doing at the moment) then you want something like:

```
// Warning: this could fail if the filename is invaild.
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("inputFileName.txt"));
```

To then read in each line, you can use the following in the while loop:

```
// Warning: this will crash the program if the line contains anything other than integers.
myIntArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())
 i = i + 1; // increment i so i is the total numbers read
```

You should also close the reader at the end:

```
try{
  br.close();
} catch (IOException e)
{
  System.out.println("Error, program exit!");
  System.exit(1);
}
```

The import should be swapped from `import java.io.InputStreamReader`
to: `import java.io.FileReader`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only reading 1 line therefore I suspect it to be a single line delimited by colon/semicolon or other character.. try looking into StringTokenizer and Scanner classes

Answer (score 0):

N = the number from parsing a string to a number
In the first part of your program it N = 5

Why are you using while(i<5)?

If anything you should be

```
r = number of lines in text file;

while (i< r)
{

readline;

parseline;

store in array;

}
```

and then sort

Comment: Im using N = 5 (or the first value of the text file) because in the specifications of the problem it says that the first value in the text file is how many values need to be read from the file. so i am using it to iterate through the file and storing the value in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the example they gave you

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        /*
         * Read input from stdin and provide input before running
         */

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = br.readLine();
        int N = Integer.parseInt(line);

        //create storage array
        int[] myIntArray = new int[N];

        //read remainder of file
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            myIntArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(line);
        }
        // close file
        br.close();


        //Perform median calculations
        int median = 0;
        ...
        System.out.println(median);
}
```

}